# asp.net MVC 4 display unicode text field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this model named `News`:

```
NewsId int,
Subjet nvarchar(100),
Content text
```

when creating a `news instance` I try to enter unicode text for content field.the problem is that this unicode content field is displayed like this:

```
????? ???? ??? 400 ????? ???? ????
```

**Note:** to display content field I do this in `view`:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Content)
```

I tryed to set unicode options in web.config:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" fileEncoding="utf-8" />
```

but It didn't work!

I also tryed `@Html.Encode(item.Content)` but no result!

**Edit:** and using this tag in head section didn't help me:
 `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

any suggestion?

**Edit:** I just found out that `News Instances` saved in database have this corrupted data for content field.as I mentioned, type of content field in database is `text` and I use this code to create a `News Instance`:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create(News news)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.News.Add(news);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(news);
}
```

but the value for content field is saved like this:

```
????? ???? ??? 400 ????? ???? ????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with this solution:

I changed the type of `content` field from `text` to `nvarchar(max)` and every thing went well.

Answer (score 0):

Try making your page utf-8 by placing the following meta header in the `<head>` section of your layout:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Another possibility is that the text is already stored corrupted in your database in which case you will have to fix the code responsible for that.

Comment: I also tryed this option and no result.

Comment: Have you verified that the data is not already corrupted in your database?

Comment: How can I possibly know why without seeing your code that is storing it?